# CSS transition bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this pair of divs that should resize on click, it works fine except that every once in a while the div kind of flashes before resizing. I done a lot of research and everybody agrees it should fix with "-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;" but I've tried it and it doesn't change anything. It fails both in chrome and firefox. I mean sometimes it works fine and other times it just flickers really horribly.

Any ideas on what is wrong?
Is it in the jquery? in the css?

Any help is appreciated.

My JS:

(function($){

```
setup = function setup(){
        var windowWidth;        

        $('.day').each(function(){

            var $this = $(this),
                links = $('.links', $this),
                images = $('.images', $this),
                largeWidth,
                smallWidth,
                linksWidth,
                imagesWidth;



                images.click(function(){

                    windowWidth = $(window).width();
                    linksWidth = $('.links', $this).width();
                    imagesWidth = $('.images', $this).width();

                    largeWidth = Math.max(linksWidth,imagesWidth);
                    smallWidth = Math.min(linksWidth,imagesWidth);

                    if (windowWidth < 850){
                        images.width(largeWidth);
                        links.width(smallWidth);
                    }


                })

                 links.click(function(){

                    windowWidth = $(window).width();
                    linksWidth = $('.links', $this).width();
                    imagesWidth = $('.images', $this).width();

                    largeWidth = Math.max(linksWidth,imagesWidth);
                    smallWidth = Math.min(linksWidth,imagesWidth);

                    if (windowWidth < 850){
                        links.width(largeWidth);
                        images.width(smallWidth);
                    }
                })


        });


}

$(document).ready(setup);

}(jQuery))
```

And the CSS:

```
.column {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: width 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: width 0.3s linear;
  transition: width 0.3s linear;

  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;

  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); 
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cKvYq/2/

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you end up resolving your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why their widths start animating less and less is because you set the width to be changed to based on the current width, so when one is clicked while it is transitioning those values are thrown off. To remedy this you could attempt to calculate the large and small width based on window size initially and on window resize, but what I recommend and the method I used is to disable the clicks using `.on` and `.off` with a `setInterval` the duration of the transition.

The other problem of the right div wrapping to the next line is caused by the width temporarily taking up more than the window width. I assume it's because sometimes the divs are just slightly animated at different times, thus one expands before the other contracts throwing it to the next line. I remedied this problem by lessening the width of both of them by a couple pixels and using a negative margin, increased padding trick to have the right div called `images` to take up that space that I removed. This part could probably be done in a cleaner way than I did it, such as including that small decrease in the initial calculation somewhere or perhaps in the CSS, but for this demo I didn't figure it was too big of an issue, it functions well and was made to show you the problem

[**Here is the Updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/cKvYq/5/)

Here is the changed jQuery

```
(function ($) {
    setup = function setup() {
        var windowWidth;
        $('.day').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                links = $('.links', $this),
                images = $('.images', $this),
                largeWidth,
                smallWidth,
                linksWidth,
                imagesWidth,
                count = 0;
            var imagesClick = function () {
                images.off('click');
                links.off('click');                
                windowWidth = $(window).width();
                if(count === 0)
                {
                    linksWidth = $('.links', $this).width() - 2;
                    imagesWidth = $('.images', $this).width() - 2;
                    images.css({'margin-right': "-=4", 'padding-right': "+=4"});
                    count++;
                } else{
                    linksWidth = $('.links', $this).width();
                    imagesWidth = $('.images', $this).width();
                }            
                largeWidth = Math.max(linksWidth, imagesWidth);
                smallWidth = Math.min(linksWidth, imagesWidth);
                if (windowWidth < 850) {
                    images.width(largeWidth);
                    links.width(smallWidth);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        images.on('click', imagesClick);
                        links.on('click', linksClick);
                    }, 300);
                }
            }
            images.on('click', imagesClick);
            var linksClick = function () {
                images.off('click');
                links.off('click');

                windowWidth = $(window).width();
                if(count === 0)
                {
                    linksWidth = $('.links', $this).width() - 2;
                    imagesWidth = $('.images', $this).width() - 2;
                    images.css({'margin-right': "-=4", 'padding-right': "+=4"});
                    count++;
                } else{
                    linksWidth = $('.links', $this).width();
                    imagesWidth = $('.images', $this).width();
                }   

                largeWidth = Math.max(linksWidth, imagesWidth);
                smallWidth = Math.min(linksWidth, imagesWidth);

                if (windowWidth < 850) {
                    links.width(largeWidth);
                    images.width(smallWidth);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        images.on('click', imagesClick);
                        links.on('click', linksClick);
                    }, 300);
                }
            }
            links.on('click', linksClick);
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(setup);
}(jQuery))
```